# Function just stops on UPDATE SQlite databse on Android

Tags: android, sql-update, android-sqlite, sqlite

I use the following method to update Database if needed, Data are retrieved from a web-service as an `JSONObject`. but seems that this method just stops working on `database.update`
(Logs after this line of code does not appear on logcat, and logcat reports no error , its strange !)

```
private void updateDB(JSONArray serverRecords) throws JSONException {

    Log.i(LOGTAG, "update db started");
for (int i = 0; i < serverRecords.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = serverRecords.getJSONObject(i);
    String pin = row.getString("pin");
    String state = isRecordUnique(pin);
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "State => " + state);
    if (state.equals("0")) {
        //makeDbReady();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "new record");
        // new record
        ContentValues inserts = new ContentValues();
        inserts.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CARD_OPERATOR,
                row.getInt("opr"));
        inserts.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CARD_TYPE, row.getString("typ"));
        inserts.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CARD_PIN, row.getString("pin"));
        inserts.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CARD_PRICE,
                row.getString("pri"));
        inserts.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE, row.getString("dte"));
        inserts.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATE, row.getInt("stt"));
        inserts.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SYNC_DATE, row.getString("syn"));

        long affected = database.insert(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null,
                inserts);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "datbase updated and " + affected
                + " rows affected");
    } else {
        //makeDbReady();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "update record, sync date => ");
        // update existing records
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_SYNC_DATE, row.getString("syn"));
        values.put(SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATE, row.getInt("stt"));
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Values: " + values.toString());
        try {
            int affected = database.update(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, values,
                SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = '" + row.getString("_id")
                        + "'", null);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.i(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        // String sqlQuery = "UPDATE `" + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME
        // + "` SET `" + SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATE + "` = '"
        // + row.getInt("stt") + "', `"
        // + SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATE + "` = '"
        // + row.getInt("stt") + "' " + "WHERE _id ='"
        // + row.getString("_id") + "'";
        // Log.i(LOGTAG, sqlQuery);
        // database.execSQL(sqlQuery);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "update sate: ");
    }
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "update method: condition did not met");
    }
}
```

I also tried to close every instance of `Cursor` object in my code.
the only possible "left-Open" cursor object is those that is passed to a method for processing, i don't know it that causes error but i also commented lines of code calling that method (to make sure no `Cursor` Object is left open before trying to update) but it didn't make any difference.

Here is the logs:

```
07-02 16:20:45.307: I/myapp(13928): update db started
07-02 16:20:45.317: I/myapp(13928): State => 4
07-02 16:20:45.317: I/myapp(13928): update record, sync date => 
07-02 16:20:45.317: I/myapp(13928): Values: state=1 sync_date=13-07-02 13:26:31
```

`SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID` is a constant and its value is: `_id`

Comment: Is your IF condition working ? I mean the insert part  ?

Comment: @benilMathew Yes, insert works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Change your datatype from `int affected`  to `long affected`

So your code should look like this

```
long affected = database.update(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, values,
                    SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = '" + row.getString("_id")
                            + "'", null);
```

Hope it works

Comment: Can you try with some data like database.update(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, values,
                    SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = '" + "121")
                            + "'", null);  where 121 can be any id which previously exist in your database

Comment: @beniMathew I tried your suggestion and it worked, what might be causing this ?

Comment: it basically something to do with your JSON object and the data it contains. It is causing the error while fetching the data from the JSON object . Log out the value you get while using row.getString("_id")

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that part

Comment: :) .. Best of luck with your proj.